# jQuery doesn't work after click on "add to cart"

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my shop products are added to cart trough **ajax** loaded, the website navigation is enabled if I click on a button, and the cart with same solution, problem is if I click on *add to cart* on product page, then I can not open navigation or cart box. This is my jQuery code and it works fine if I don't click on *add to cart*.

```
var animationSpeed = 500;

$('#webtouch').on('click',function() {

    if($('#sidebarcart').hasClass('sidebarvisible')) {
        $('#sidebarcart').removeClass('sidebarvisible', animationSpeed);
        $('#websitebox').removeClass('websiteboxmove', animationSpeed);
        $('#sidebar').addClass('sidebarvisible', animationSpeed);
        $('#websitebox').addClass('websiteboxmove', animationSpeed);
    } else {
        $('#websitebox').toggleClass('websiteboxmove', animationSpeed);
        $('#sidebar').toggleClass('sidebarvisible', animationSpeed);
    }

});
```

How can I set that so this script also work after *add to cart*? There are no other JS errors in my browser console.

Comment: removeClass, addClass doesn't have a second argument at all

Comment: Not enough information to answer question - you need to also show us the code to "add to cart." Obviously, the "add to cart" code has an unwanted side effect, but unless I can see that code, I have no idea what it is.

Comment: @JGDarvell this is custom shop script from hikashop, an example is here: http://demo.hikashop.com/index.php?option=com_hikashop&ctrl=product&task=show&cid=49&name=japanese-garden&Itemid=80&lang=en